# How to extract from a JSON Array in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

i have a JSON Array:

```
[
    {"leagueId":"52dd22c0-0f4a-41e8-8au2-c81f66dacb43",
        "leagueName":"League1",
        "tier":"PLATINUM",
        "queueType":"RANKED_SOLO",
        "rank":"V",
        "leaguePoints":0,
        "wins":131, 
        "losses":117,
        "hotStreak":false}
]
```

and i want to extract the 'tier' data.

I only know it with objects: `f = responseJSON ['tier']`, but how does it work with an array?

Comment: `jsonobject[0]['tier']`?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to convert your `json` data to `dict` using json.loads, then you can access `dict` key easily.

```
In [23]: x = """
    ...: [
    ...:     {"leagueId":"52dd22c0-0f4a-41e8-8au2-c81f66dacb43",
    ...:         "leagueName":"League1",
    ...:         "tier":"PLATINUM",
    ...:         "queueType":"RANKED_SOLO",
    ...:         "rank":"V",
    ...:         "leaguePoints":0,
    ...:         "wins":131,
    ...:         "losses":117,
    ...:         "hotStreak":false}
    ...: ]
    ...: """

In [24]: import json

In [25]: x = json.loads(x)

In [26]: x
Out[26]:
[{u'hotStreak': False,
  u'leagueId': u'52dd22c0-0f4a-41e8-8au2-c81f66dacb43',
  u'leagueName': u'League1',
  u'leaguePoints': 0,
  u'losses': 117,
  u'queueType': u'RANKED_SOLO',
  u'rank': u'V',
  u'tier': u'PLATINUM',
  u'wins': 131}]

In [27]: x[0]['tier']
Out[27]: u'PLATINUM'

In [28]:
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using code like this:

```
json_array = [
    {
        "leagueId":"52dd22c0-0f4a-41e8-8au2-c81f66dacb43",
        "leagueName":"League1",
        "tier":"PLATINUM",
        "queueType":"RANKED_SOLO",
        "rank":"V",
        "leaguePoints":0,
        "wins":131, 
        "losses":117,
        "hotStreak":False
    }
]

new_list = [dic['tier'] for dic in json_array]
```

then `new_list` will include all the `tier`s.

Comment: `json_array` have invalid python values like `false` You need to convert json to dict.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. But I thought it been already parsed by parser like `requests`'s `.json()` method :)

Answer (score 0):

The array is simply a list of length (1). So, you would retrieve the json dict by calling the array's first index - and then calling the get() method to retrieve the value in the dictionary:

```
responseJSON = {...}

f = responseJSON [0]['tier'] # value of f: 'PLATINUM'
```